# How to Handle QueryTimeoutException?

Tags: hibernate

How to handle QueryTimeoutException in Spring-Hibernate.I am getting the following exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/QueryTimeoutException

Comment: print your full stack trace of that `NoClassDefFoundError`. thats mean some of your class is missing or wrong mapping.

Comment: be sure you have the following dependency in your project  
<dependency>  
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>  
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>  
<version>4.3.5.Final</version>  
</dependency>